# Composing ActiveRecord scopes with selects

Tags: activerecord, arel

Unfortunately, ActiveRecord's `select` replaces the existing `SELECT` clause instead of adding to it, so I can't compose queries. Does anyone have a workaround?

Example model:

```
class Story
  scope :recent, -> { where("created_at >= ?", 1.month.ago) }

  # deliberately simple examples, please don't get distracted memoizing, etc.
  scope :with_net_score, -> { select("`stories`.*, (upvotes - downvotes) as net_score" }
  scope :with_recent, -> { select("`stories.*, greatest(updated_at, last_vote_at) as recent") }
end
```

So while I can compose `Story.recent.with_net_score`, `Story.with_net_score.with_recent` fails. And *both* `with_net_score` and `with_recent` fail when `Story` comes after a join to an association.

How would you rewrite `with_net_score` so that it adds to the fields selected instead of replcaing them and can be composed with `with_recent` and joins?

Answer (score 0):

Adding the author's own solution to this:

```rb
class ApplicationRecord < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :select_fix, -> { select(self.arel_table.project(Arel.star)) }
end
```

https://github.com/lobsters/lobsters/blob/master/app/models/application_record.rb